# query mysql database using php for plotting with morris.js

Tags: php, mysql, morris.js

I have a mysql database i would like to query with this format.
Note: In the real dataset there are more categories in the series field 
so the aswer should be able to handle an unknown amount of categories (in this case there are just two: licensed and sorned)

```
period          series      values
1349046000000   licensed    3407        
1349046000000   sorned      660
1313103600000   licensed    3351   
1313103600000   sorned      629
```

I can't find the way to convert this table using php to the
format required by the morris.js library. Such as:
(following this [example](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/blob/master/examples/timestamps.html))

```
{"period": 1349046000000, "licensed": 3407, "sorned": 660},
{"period": 1313103600000, "licensed": 3351, "sorned": 629}
```

Here is the php code i've tried to write, but it outputs a wrong format, it's just the table. The required output of the library should have each serie as columns in "wide" format.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","martin");
mysql_select_db('table');
$query = "select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(period) * 1000 as period, series, values from table";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$data = array();

while($data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution in php to pivot the table to "feed" a morris.js chart.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","martin");
mysql_select_db('table');

// First query the fields of the pivot table
$query_fields = "SELECT series dominio from table";
$result_fields = mysql_query($query_fields);

$var = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_fields)) {
    $var[] = $row['series'];
}

// Here i write the "pivot" query dinamically
foreach($var as $i){
    $query2 .= ",MAX(CASE WHEN series = '$i' THEN values END) as $i";
}

$query1 = "SELECT period ";
$query3 = " FROM
            table
            group by 1";

$query_pivot = $query1 . $query2 . $query3;
$result_pivot = mysql_query($query_pivot);

$output = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_pivot)){
    $output[] = $row;
}

//print_r($output);
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Now using an ajax call i can get morris.js to plot this

Answer (score -1):

Do you have control over the database design? That's a pretty bad setup.

If you were able to set up the database like this:

```
period          licensed    sorned
1349046000000   3407        660
1313103600000   3351        629
```

You can then extract the data appropriately:

```
$query = "select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(period) * 1000 as period, licensed, sorned from table";
```